# bash loop through all find recursively in sub-directories

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I have a bash script that looks like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=public_html/*.php  # */ stupid syntax highlighter!
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
  # take action on each file.
done
```

Now I need it to go through all subdirectories in `public_html` so it should run on:

```
/public_html/index.php
/public_html/forums/status.php
/public_html/really/deep/file/in/many/sub/dirs/here.php
```

What do I change `FILES=public_html/*.php` to in order to do that?

Also I need to check to make sure that there is at least one file or else it prints

```
Processing *.php file...
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
FILES=$(find public_html -type f -name '*.php')
```

**IMPORTANT:** Note the single quotes around the `*.php` to prevent shell expansion of the `*`.

Comment: It's only returning results from the pwd.

Comment: I don't think so. (Do you using GNU's find?) `mkdir -p public_html/{a,b,c}; touch public_html/{a,b,c}/{1,2,3}.php; find public_html -type f -name *.php` returns all 9 files.

Comment: This worked `FILES="$(find public_html -type f -name '*.php')"`

Comment: You might have had spaces in some file names, putting quotes around the whole thing quotes each individual match.

Comment: Also, $() means run the command inside the braces and make a string out of the standard output that results.

Comment: Is there a way we can we do this when there are spaces in the directory names? When I loop through $FILES it is breaking on the spaces.

Answer (score 2):

```
FILES=`find public_html -type d`
```

$FILES will now be a list of every single directory inside public_html.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I need to get the files inside the directory and not the directories themselves

Comment: You want every php file in the subdirectories of public_html? In that case you can write 
    `find public_html -name *.php`